# collective.tabr kupu modification

Tags: plone

I am using the collective.kuputabs module and have added the collective.tabr add-on so that I can create a page with multiple tabs. It works fine. However, I see bullets beside the tabs and I want to delete them. Here is a snap shot of how it looks:

[image: Snapshot]

Where will the code for this be stored?. Tabs is a library in Kupu Visual Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Firebug to explore the CSS, then override it in ploneCustom.css (ZMI>portal_skins>custom) or your own custom theme product.